# Prevent git from removing local directory which is in git ignore for initial git setup

Tags: git

I have a wordpress project in which I want to setup git on a server. I also want to add the wp-content/plugins directory in .gitignore so it remains unaffected during the git setup. But when I did this on my local, the plugins folder gets deleted.

I tried this

1. Reset master to initial commit to get the plugins folder and contents and which doesnt have plugins in gitignore
2. git rm --cached -r wp-content/plugins/
3. git pull to get the commit which deleted the plugins folder and puts the plugins in gitignore.

But it still deletes the plugins folder.

> How do I prevent git from deleting the plugins and also the uploads folder? The plugins folder also should not be in the master branch

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prevent git from deleting [these] folder[s]?

Put some file(s) in them.

#### What's going on here

Git is not really interested in directories / folders (you called them directories first, then later, folders, so I use both terms here).  Git is interested in, and stores, *files*.  As far as Git is concerned, files have—or can have—long-ish names with parts that your *OS* insists on treating in folder-ish ways.  For instance, Git might store a file named `wp-content/plugins/file.ext`.  Your *OS* demands that this be stored as a file named `file.ext` in a folder named `plugins` in a folder named `wp-content`.  That's your OS's problem, not Git's, but it becomes Git's problem the moment Git goes to *extract* the file named `wp-content/plugins/file.ext` from some commit, to an ordinary file on your computer.

At that point, Git will *create* `wp-content` if needed, then create `wp-content/plugins` if needed, so that it can create the file that, to Git, is named `wp-content/plugins/file.ext`.  Git did not *store* these folders anywhere.  It *stored* the *file* `wp-content/plugins/file.ext` (in a commit) and then you told it "take that commit and make it available to me" so then it *created* the two directories because your OS insists on this folder-and-file structure.

Because the OS insists, Git will *create* directories / folders on demand.  By the same token, when Git removes a *committed* file—because you're switching away from that commit, to some other commit that *lacks* that file—Git will clean up after itself by *removing* a directory / folder, if that's the last file that forces Git to accommodate the OS by having that directory / folder exist.

Git cannot and therefore will not remove the directory / folder if some other sub-directory/folder or some file exists within the directory.  So if you have any untracked files in there, for instance, Git won't touch the directory.

Note that `git clean -df` *will* remove empty directories from the work-tree, whether or not Git created them.  This is all due to the fact that Git does not store information about directories/folders in its *index*.  The index is the thing from which Git builds new commits. The index is very central to Git: it's where merges really happen; it's where new commits are built; and it caches information *about* an extracted commit, to make Git run fast.

In general, between one Git command and the next, Git doesn't remember any directories it created.  All it does is:

- remove a commit's files from the index, and if you've told it to update your work-tree, remove those same files from the work-tree; and
- load a commit into the index, and if you've told it to update your work-tree, replace those files with their committed (and now index copy) versions.

Because the index does not keep track of directories—only *files*, with long names like `wp-content/plugins/file.ext`—Git literally cannot *store* an empty folder.<sup>1</sup>  That's why it uses this "create when needed, remove when removing the last file" trick.

Because Git uses the "remove a work-tree folder when removing its last file", the *only* thing that *stops* Git from removing such a directory/folder is to leave some file in it.  This can be a *committed* file, such as an empty `.gitignore` or empty `.keep` or whatever you like, or just some untracked file.  If it's some untracked file, Git itself won't *create* the directory either: you will have to do that.

See the footnote link for the way to use an empty submodule instead of a dummy `.gitignore`, but I will note that if I were doing this I'd just use a dummy `.gitignore` (probably *not* an empty one, but rather one with one line reading `*`).

---

<sup>1</sup>It can, however, store a *submodule*, via a gitlink, and a gitlink can point to a repository that has no files.  Hence, [the empty submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/1256452) *does* actually work to store an empty directory!  It's kind of a shame that the index can't store a mode `40000` directory, because if it could, Git *could* store and manage empty folders, without resorting to the "use the empty submodule" trick.